# Cloudbees Jenkins: Triggering a downstream job between in a different Jenkins instance

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, cloudbees

Objective: To trigger a downstream job from a different Jenkins instance and display the console output in the upstream job.
Job type: Pipeline scripts.

The complete code below:

```
properties([
        parameters([                        
            string(name: 'var1', defaultValue: "value1", description: ''),
            string(name: 'var2', defaultValue: "value2", description: ''),
            string(name: 'var3', defaultValue: "value3", description: '')           
        ])
]) 

node('unique tag'){

    stage("Trigger downstream"){

        //From Jenkins
        def remoteRunWrapper = triggerRemoteJob(
                    mode: [$class: 'ConfirmStarted', timeout: [timeoutStr: '1h'], whenTimeout: [$class: 'StopAsFailure']],
                    remotePathMissing: [$class: 'StopAsFailure'],
                    parameterFactories: [[$class: 'SimpleString', name: 'var1', value: var1], [$class: 'SimpleString', name: 'var2', value: var2], [$class: 'SimpleString', name: 'var3', value: var3]], 
                    remotePathUrl: 'jenkins://..',
                    )

        print(remoteRunWrapper.toString())
        //would want to use other capabilities offered by remoteRunWrapper
    }
}
```

The `triggerRemoteJob` is able to trigger the downstream job and return with an instance of `RemoteRunWrapper` after the job has started. The `RemoteRunWrapper` instance should provide capabilities that can allow me to check on the downstream job/retrieve logs. There is however no documentation on the `RemoteRunWrapper` that I could find. The methods described in the `RunWrapper` [documentation](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html) cannot be used and the script fails with the error:

`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.cloudbees.opscenter.triggers.RemoteRunWrapper.getId() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`

**How can I find the capabilities offered by `RemoteRunWrapper`? Are there any better ways to achieve this?**

Note:

1) The use of

```
mode: [$class: 'ConfirmStarted', timeout: [timeoutStr: '1h'], whenTimeout: [$class: 'StopAsFailure']],
remotePathUrl: 'jenkins://...'
```

is necessary as the below:

```
remoteJenkinsUrl: 'https://myjenkins:8080/...'
job: 'TheJob'
```

from the `triggerRemoteJob` [documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-remote-trigger-plugin/blob/master/README_PipelineConfiguration.md) is failing to trigger the job and is returning a null object and the methods that are described [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-remote-trigger-plugin/blob/master/README_PipelineConfiguration.md) also cause the script to fail with `MissingMethodException`.

2) The `[$class: 'RemoteBuildConfiguration']` provides an option `'enhancedLogging'` that allows the console output of the remote job to also be logged. However when used, a `classNotFound` exception is seen (import statement was included).

3) It does not really matter whether the downstream job is triggered asynchronous or synchronously as long as it is possible to log the console output of the downstream job in the console output of the upstream job.

Comment: Note, that documentation for this CloudBees feature is at the [Cluster-wide job triggers](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/pipelines/cluster-triggers). None of the documentation links in the question apply.